# In spite vs Out of spite

Tags: differences

Do these two sentences below mean basically the same?

*He spoke **out of spite.***
*He spoke **in spite.***

Would there be a nuance, what would it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't necessarily.

"He spoke out of spite" **always** means something along the lines "He spoke out of hatefulness/malevolence".

"In spite" CAN mean exactly the same thing, but does not have to. It can also mean "anyway/regardless of".

"He spoke in spite of his father's warning" means "He said something, even though his father warned him not to".

However, as your sample sentences don't contain any further information to go with, "in spite" and "out of spite" do mean the same thing in this particular case.